# Windows FTP Server with temporary file locking/renaming capabilities

Tags: windows, ftp

Do you know of a Windows-based FTP server that will receive files, but temporarily rename them as .tmp files during the upload. When complete, rename it to the original filename. This should ensure that the file cannot be accessed until the transfer is fully complete.

I am currently using FileZilla Server and I do not think it has this capability. I believe the feature I am looking for is similar to the "lock_upload_files" configuration for vsftpd.

Comment: Darius, I'm sorry, but product and service recommendation questions are OT for SF, and all SE sites.  Read the FAQ for details on why.

Answer (score 2):

I would try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) which would enable you to run [proftpd](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_HiddenStores.html) with "Hidden Stores" enabled. As far as I can tell that is the equivelent to vsftpd's "lock_upload_files".

> The HiddenStores directive enables two-step file uploads: files are uploaded as ".in.filename." and once the upload is complete, renamed to just "filename".